How to scroll till specific element using java automation code
I have tried with many to use scroll function to scroll till element is visible and click on it I used javascript executer, actions but yet I am not able to scroll.Below is the method provided.
public void clickkAdropdownOption() throws InterruptedException {
//      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", knowledgeAugmentationBtn);
//      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(0,250)");
//       WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated( (By) knowledgeAugmentationBtn);
//         
//         js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", knowledgeAugmentationBtn);

         Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
         actions.moveToElement(knowledgeAugmentationBtn).perform();
//         actions.doubleClick(knowledgeAugmentationBtn).build().perform();

As I need a scroll function where I can scroll till element is visible and click on it as method is added above

if the element is already found just use .click() on it.  (click method will automatically scroll into view)  If it's not in the DOM until you scroll you can use something like window.scrollBy... or element.scroll...
